# invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'

Tags: r

My code is as below

```
Fun2<-function(x){
                  x$dportfolio<-with(x, cut(x$coef, 
                  breaks=quantile(x$coef, probs=seq(0,1, by=0.1), na.rm=FALSE), 
                  include.lowest=TRUE,
                  labels=c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")))
                  }

Data.1936.dsort.1<-aggregate(Data.1936.dsort,Data.1936.dsort$portfolio,FUN = Fun2)
```

I kept getting the error message  Error

```
in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()) : 
  invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

What I want to do is to apply this function to each group, for each group I creating subgroups

Comment: The by argument for `aggregate` is supposed to be a list. You are giving it an atomic vector. I must admit that I don't remember getting this error when I made that mistake in hte past, so you are advised to post a small subset of Data.1936.dsort using `dput`.

Comment: I changed it to a list, but still got a error message like this.